# How to test a promise returned by an external module using axios.create in Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

I am trying to test a promise returned by a module outside of my code that uses axios.create to make the call. To test that it is looking inside the .then and .catch I am only setting the state again but it doesn't take that into consideration. What exactly do I need to tell Jest to do in order to test what happens inside of the .then and .catch?

I have tried to mock the module and also spy on the method 'get' but none of them work.

File.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { request } from '../../../../global/Helper';

class File extends Component {
  constructor() {
    This.state = {
      isLoading: false,
      number: 5
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchStates();
  };
  fetchStates = () => {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    request.get('/api/state/')
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({ number: 10 });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      this.setState({ number: 15 });
    });
  };
};

export { ProfileEdit };
```

Helper.js

```
import axios from 'axios';

let request = axios.create({
  baseURL: `${process.env.BASE_URL}`,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  crossDomain: true,
  responseType: 'json'
});

export { request };
```

File.test.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Helper from '../../../../global/Helper';
import { File } from './File';

describe('File', () => {
  const props = {
    location: {
      state: {
      }
    },
  };

 it('should set the state twice', (done) => {
    // Arrange
    let component = mount(<ProfileEdit {...props}/>).instance();
    let setStateSpy = spyOn(ProfileEdit.prototype, 'setState');

    jest.spyOn(Helper.request, 'get').mockResolvedValue();

    // Act
    component.fetchStates();

    //Assert
    expect(setStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({ number: 10 }));
    done();
  });

});
```

I expect it setstate to be called twice but it is only calling it once.

This is the error message I get:

```
 expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(expected)

    Expected spy to have been called with:
      ObjectContaining {"number": 10}
    as argument 1, but it was called with
      {"isLoading": true}.

    Difference:

    - Expected
    + Received

    - ObjectContaining {
    -   "number": 10,
    + Object {
    +   "isLoading": true,
      }

      46 |     component.fetchStates();
      47 | 
    > 48 |     expect(setStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({ number: 10 }));
         |                         ^
      49 |     done();
      50 |   });
      51 | });
```

Comment: Why do you expect `setState()` to be called twice? Where should these calls occur during your test? Which lines? Also I suggest expecting against the component's state directly, then you don't have to spy on setState().

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I forgot to add that I am setting the state before the request. The main issue I have is that I cannot find a way to test what is inside of the .then even though I have tried to use 'mockFn.mockResolvedValue(value)'.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the call to `this.setState()` inside of your `then()` callback isn't being called. This is most likely because the test is finishing before the promise can be resolved or rejected. You can start by returning the promise:

```
fetchStates = () => {
    return request.get('/api/state/')
        .then(response => {
            this.setState({ number: 10 });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.setState({ number: 15 });
        });
}
```

Now you can get the promise inside of your test and chain a `then()` on it:

```
 it('should set the state twice', (done) => {
    // Arrange
    let component = mount(<ProfileEdit {...props}/>).instance();
    let setStateSpy = spyOn(ProfileEdit.prototype, 'setState');

    jest.spyOn(Helper.request, 'get').mockResolvedValue();

    // Act
    return component.fetchStates()
        .then(function() {
            //Assert
            expect(setStateSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.objectContaining({ number: 10 }));
            done();
        });
  });
```

Note that the promise is also returned from your test. Jest will then take this promise and allow it to resolve/reject before printing any output about your test.

**Suggestion:** expecting `this.setState()` to be called requires that your test depends on details of the function that is tested. It is better to expect against the final state of the component directly because then your test no longer relies on the number of times `this.setState()` is called. If you do this, then you have to be careful to make sure jest resolves all of the promises.

Comment: Sorry! I forgot to add that I am also setting the state once before the request call! That is why I am checking for setState to be called twice. The main issue I have is that I cannot find a way to test what is inside of the .then even though I have tried to use 'mockFn.mockResolvedValue(value)'.

Comment: `I forgot to add that I am also setting the state once before the request call!` Please add that detail to your code example.

Comment: @PaolaArredondo See my edited answer that shows how to resolve the promise in your test.